# See all instances of a running program - keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10

After spending many years in the MacOS environment, I've come back to Windows for heavy-lifting tasks that my little '15 Air can't handle.  Problem is I am missing many of the features that Mac provides in terms of navigation.  One of which is the ability to see all instances of a program i.e. web browser, running in one view (three-finger swipe gesture).  Would anyone be able to recommend how to best achieve this, and *potentially* other Mac-like gestures if at all possible?  Is there a program out there that is able to customize the Windows experience a bit more?  **For anyone interested, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> was remedied via https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/**  Can't live without it.

Thank you for your suggestions and thoughts.

Comment: Use the Task Bar, where windows of the same program are always grouped when the cursor hovers over any of their windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Windows` key +`Tab` key to show the task view. As a former MacOS user myself, it is the closest we can get. It shows all of the running applications, allows you to create new desktops, move apps between desktops, the whole nine yards.